# Не работает программка поворота домножением на матрицу

Tags: python, tkinter

Пробовал сделать поворот объекта матричным методом, вроде все правильно и по форумлам (умножение вектора, задающего точку, на матрицу поворота), но почему-то оборот совершается только максимум на на pi/4 после чего замирает. Пробовал поменять знаки, там вообще какая-то ерунда начинает твориться. В общем, буду признателен, если укажите, что ограничивает поворот.

```
from Tkinter import *  
from math import *  

root=Tk()  
root.geometry('750x700')  

c = Canvas(root,width=700,height=700,bg="white")  
c.place(x=0, y=0)  

x0 = 350  
y0 = 350  

x1 = 350  
y1 = 350  
x2 = 350  
y2 = 10  

line = c.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2,  width=3)  

a = pi/4  

def pov(event):  
    global x2  
    global y2  
    global a  

    r3 = (x2-x0)  
    r4 = (y2-y0)  


    x2 = r3*cos(a) + (r4)*sin(a)  
    y2 = r3*sin(a) + (r4)*cos(a)  

    c.coords(line,x1,y1,x2,y2)  



button1 = Button(root,width=3,height=3, font=10)  
button1.place(x = 720, y = 300)  
button1.bind("<Button-1>",pov)  


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное что забыли назад сдвиг сделать (прибавить координаты центра назад). По мелочи: `у` вас угл (`a`) не изменяется. Знак минус ещё нужен, чтобы по часовой стрелке вращать (`y` вниз направлен). Вычитать нужно `x1`,`y1` или их тоже нужно вращать относительно `x0`,`y0`. `x2`, `y2` не нужно изменять, только угл (`a`). В итоге ваш код превращается:

```
angle = 0  # radians

def rotate(_):
    global angle
    angle += 30 * math.pi / 180
    angle %= 2 * math.pi
    x, y = (x2-x1), (y2-y1)  # rotate relative x1,y1
    c, s = math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)
    x, y = x*c - y*s, x*s + y*c
    canvas.coords(line, x1, y1, x + x1, y + y1)
```